# What is the best way to add a form based on another in Visual Studio Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

The utility I'm building will have several forms that are very similar to each other in appearance (the code behind the forms will differ, so I don't want to use one form for all of it, to avoid a big jumbled up mess). Rather than recreate each form one at a time, I'd like to "inherit" from the existing form. Is there a canonical way of doing this with Winforms?

If not, I'll select all of the controls on the form and paste them into the new ones...

Comment: [Windows Forms Visual Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx1155fz.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i get you, you want to copy all the controls from one form to another form.

There are two ways i know

1.) Create a docked panel on the main form and add all the controls to the panel and when you want to paste you use.

```
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form = new Form1();
        this.Controls.Add(form.panel1);
    }
```

2.) Use Inheritance. After Creating the Controls in the main form, in the second form you use

```
    public partial class Form2 : Form1
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

This will automatically copy all the controls to the new form